# AngularJS getting endless loop with $q

Tags: angularjs

I m trying to get to know if user has a webcam on his computer and if he has, changing the view. How it works is, waiting a response from a callback which originally in the api  and then return true or false. But it freezes and when i do a console log, i m getting endless console logs.. What can cause this ?

Service

```
'use strict';
angular.module("browserSupportService")

        .factory("browsersCameraSupportService", function($q) {

            return {

                supportsGetUserMedia: function() {

                    navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

                    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                            navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
                                return resolve(true);
                            }, function() {
                                return resolve(false);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

Function in controller :

```
$scope.browserSupportsGetUserMedia = function () {

              browsersCameraSupportService.supportsGetUserMedia().then(function(supported) {
                console.log("no camera")
                if (!supported) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });
```

Comment: Not obvious why from the code above. How do you call `browserSupportsGetUserMedia`? You have no else case for `if (navigator.getUserMedia)` The promise might not get resolved.

Comment: it is resolved , tried to debug...

Comment: @AkinDönmez, if it solved, could you add the solution as a response?

Comment: no i mean the promise returns true as a value inside of supported.. the only issue here is it is inside of the function.. i dont know why but when
browserSupportsGetUserMedia is a variable inside of  browsersCameraSupportService.supportsGetUserMedia().then(function(supported)  then everything works.. just i dont understand why..

Comment: your code works as expected for me. Please see https://jsbin.com/zezisa/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0):

I think your promise might never be resolving itself, since according to the MDN documentation:

> Prompts the user for permission to use one video and/or one audio input device such as a camera or screensharing and/or a microphone. If the user provides permission, then the successCallback is invoked with the resulting MediaStream object as its argument. If the user denies permission or media is not available, then the errorCallback is called with PermissionDeniedError or NotFoundError respectively. **Note that it is possible for neither completion callback to be called, as the user is not required to make a choice.**

There is also the issue with the **if(navigator.getUserMedia)** , than on not present, your promise never fulfills.

So, I would suggest to set a timeout limit waiting on the user resolution and if not, resolve the promise as false, and if resolved, remove the Timeout. And, of course, handle the if issue.

Something like:

```
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    var timeBomb = setTimeout(function(){resolve(false);}, 5000);
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, function(localMediaStream) {
        clearTimeout(timeBomb);
        return resolve(true);
    }, function() {
        clearTimeout(timeBomb);
        return resolve(false);
    });
}else{
    resolve(false);
}
```